# Codeigniter not printing peso sign

Tags: html, codeigniter

my problem is that instead of peso sign "₱" it print "Â‚±" I already tried including the character in config but nothing happens.

Comment: You need to set the content-type of the page to be UTF-8. Either set an appropriate HTTP header or use a `<meta>` tag.

Comment: <meta charset="UTF-8"> is this what you mean? I have it in my header

Comment: in your config file you should have $config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';

Comment: By default codeigniter already did that. I have that in my config file. nothing happens

Comment: where does the Peso sign come from? is it hard-coded in your view or does it come from a database value?

Comment: it is hard coded